# Why i need 2 pairs of parenthesis to declare a number list

Tags: python, list, iterable

maybe seems dum but I know that if I want to declare a list I can do it this way:

```
list1 = list("Hello")
```

But why I need 2 sets of parenthesis to declare it for numbers:

```
list2 = list((2,3,4,5))
```

Comment: You are making as list from a tuple. You could just use: `[2,3,4,5]`

Comment: because "Hello" is already a list of characters. 2345 is an integer.

Comment: You need 0 parentheses if you use brackets: `list3 = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: `t= 2,3,4,5; list(t)` works though, which i know can be counter-intuative for some- the semantics to allow tuples based on commas alone, but not in certain situations where it leads to ambiguity

Comment: The semantics don't just *allow* commas alone; the commas are what *define* the tuple. The parentheses are just there to disambiguate different uses of commas. `f(2,3,4)` is a function call with three arguments, while `f((2,3), 4)` is a call with a tuple argument and a second integer argument. `t = 2,3,4,5` and `t = (2,3,4,5)` are equivalent, because there's no confusion over what the commas on the RHS of the first assignment could mean.

Comment: @chepner Yes exactly, you explained it better!

Answer (score 7):

The [docs state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

```
list()  Convert an iterable (tuple, string, set, dictionary) to a list.
```

The function `list` only takes a **single** iterable argument; `list(1,2,3,4)` would be a `TypeError`. Since a string is an iterable in python, it is a correct function call. In order to use your integers you need to convert them to some form of iterable.

By writing `list2 = list((2,3,4,5))` you convert the integers to a tuple, which is iterable.

Comment: I am confused in the use of parenthesis. Since lists are declarable with []. why i cant declare it like this: list1 = list([1,2,3,4,5])

Comment: more accurately, without the extra `(...)` OP is passing _multiple_ parameters to a function that takes a _single_ iterable parameter.

Comment: You can declare a list as `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `list([1, 2, 3, 4])` but that is redundant.

Comment: If you want to learn more about iterables you can read this https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator

Comment: The main point to understand is that `list` does not take a variable number of arguments, with each argument treated as a separate element for the new list.

Comment: "since numbers are not iterable but strings are"-- not really relevant for this case, but would be relevant if they did `list(1)`

Answer (score 2):

[list()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-list) constructs a list from an Iterable. In your examples, a string is an iterable (a sequence of chars as people have pointed out), and a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) is also an iterable (using the round brackets).

In your example you're passing a tuple to the `list()` function.

You can skip using the in-built `list()` function and create a list directly using square brackets:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are calling list() on a str which implicitly can covert to a sequence of chars. If you look closely, for the ints, you are calling list() on a tuple of ints.

Not sure if you are exploring, but the most direct way to do this is list2 = [2,3,4,5]